# Date conversion issue.: yyyy/MM/dd to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a date column where the date format is

```
2010-04-14
```

in SQL Server. Is there any possible way to retrieve the date format as

```
14/04/2010
```

in a select statement?

Comment: Your date column **doesn't have** any string format associated with it. SQL Server stores a date as a numeric value - what you see is only a **string representation** of your date. So to change that, just use a different format for the representation of that date.

Comment: Use `CONVERT` to convert the date to a string format of your choice - [here's the complete list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) of all date formats that SQL Server supports - take your pick! For your case, use `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 103)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

[Source Link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Addendum 1:

As described in my comment, you need to convert your field to a `DATETIME` type before the above will work. This example should work on your SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('2010-04-14' AS DATETIME), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

If you get this exception:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Then you need to change your date field to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` Format, EG: 2010-14-04

**OR**

Add the following line before the select statement:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY -- Input dates are in the MM/DD/YYYY format, change to DMY to handle UK dates
```

Example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('2010-04-14' AS DATETIME), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

Comment: still i'm getting the date format as 2010-04-14.i need it as 14/04/2010

Comment: as you said i'm getting the exception.can u plz tell me how can i change the date field to be in YYYY-MM-DD Format.thanx

Comment: @StuartBlackler example is different from `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem:

```
select substring(columnName, 9, 2) + '/' + substring(columnName, 6, 2)  + '/' + substring(columnName, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Or just use `SET DATEFORMAT MDY` then the is no string operations

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying that date *outside* of SqlServer, a better way would be to retrieve that date **as date** and convert it to the string-representation you want just before displaying it.

How to do that depends on your situation.

Answer (score -1):

```
select replace(datetime,'-','/')
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, which is to change both the separators and the order of the date components.