# SQL INNER JOINS in SP converting date and/or time from character string getting error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have searched about 20 results apertaining to the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." and none seem to address my issue.

A little history, last Friday the queries were working just fine and the data returned was proper. On the following Monday, the queries no longer worked and gave this error message, "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  So, after a few hours of battling it was able to run a function with the offending code in it and the query ran perfect again. Until this morning. I came into the office and ran the query and received the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  So now I am pulling my hair out.

I started by verifying each record being returned is, in fact, a valid date using the isDate function. All the dates are valid dates in string format. I am simply doing a check to see whether or not the record is older than 1 year.

I do have several INNER JOINS and have been wondering if they are affecting the output.

```
SELECT 
gc2p.partnumber, gc2p.orderby, gc2p.campaigncode, gp2a.assetfilename
FROM [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2productrefs] gc2p
,[StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getpimweblegalattrlist1] gpwa
,[StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2assetrefs] gc2a 
,[StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getproduct2assetrefs] gp2a 
WHERE gc2p.partnumber=gpwa.PARTNUMBER and
gc2p.id=gc2a.id and
gp2a.PRODUCTNAME=gpwa.PARTNUMBER and
ATTRIBUTENAME='New Date' AND 
ATTRIBUTEVALUE > dateadd(month,-12,getdate()) AND 
gc2p.id = '5665976' and 
gc2a.assettype='Primary Image' AND 
gp2a.ASSETTYPE = 'Primary Image'
order by gc2p.orderby
```

If anyone could give me a helping hand that would be wonderful.

Edit: The query runs fine when I remove 'ATTRIBUTEVALUE > dateadd(month,-12,getdate())'. I forgot to mention the exact part of the query throwing the error.

Edit: Updated Query - **Now Working Query** for those seeking a similar answer.

```
SELECT TOP 18 gc2p.partnumber, gpwa.ATTRIBUTECNAME,gp2a.ASSETFILENAME, gpwa.ATTRIBUTEVALUE
FROM [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2productrefs] gc2p
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getpimweblegalattrlist1] gpwa ON gc2p.partnumber=gpwa.PARTNUMBER and gpwa.ORDERBY='96'
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getclassification2assetrefs] gc2a ON gc2p.id=gc2a.id
INNER JOIN [StepMirror].[dbo].[stepview_nwppck_ngn_getproduct2assetrefs] gp2a ON gc2p.partnumber=gp2a.PRODUCTNAME
WHERE gc2p.id = 5665976 AND gp2a.assettype='Primary Image' AND gc2a.assettype='Primary Image' 
AND(CASE WHEN ISDATE(ATTRIBUTEVALUE)  = 0 then NULL ELSE ATTRIBUTEVALUE END) > dateadd(month,-12,getdate())
order by gc2p.orderby
```

Comment: What format are your dates in? And what language is your executing user set to? This might help if you want to test: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9126277/315711

Comment: What datatype is the column `ATTRIBUTEVALUE`?, is the only one that is suppossed to be a date?. Oh, and just as a good practice, you should change your implicit joins to explicit ones.

Comment: joins can cause tupples you don't expect. if you run the join with no where, are there any tupples where ATTRIBUTEVALUE is null? this can happen even if there are no nulls in the source table being joined.

Comment: ATTRIBUTEVALUE is nvarchar(1700) and can house any type of data (partnumber, description text, date, etc.)  Language is English.

Comment: Date format in the database tables is  YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: This is why the EAV pattern is terrible.

Comment: @HeatherRoberts if you're going to allow multiple attributes to be stored in the same column, it seems a bit counter-intuitive to force them all to be `datetime` when you report on them, no?

Comment: @HeatherRoberts US English or British English?

Comment: ... and i believe that Frank meant [`tuples`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that you have non-date data in the ATTRIBUTEVALUE field.  You're assuming that including the `ATTRIBUTENAME='New Date'` will filter it, but it may not depending upon the query plan.  Try...

```
(CASE WHEN ISDATE(ATTRIBUTEVALUE) = 0 then NULL ELSE ATTRIBUTEVALUE END) > dateadd(month,-12,getdate()) AND ...
```

In complex joins, the SQL engine may decide to join the tables first then use the filter, which will cause a mismatch is not every instance of `ATTRIBUTEVALUE` will convert implicitly to a date.

Also, please use real SQL joins, not comma joins.  It's bad form and causes way more problems than it solves.

Comment: I'm getting a "Incorrect Syntax near ')'" error message off that case statement. My jedi sql skills are lacking.

Comment: It's not only likely, but it's probable given this, "ATTRIBUTEVALUE is nvarchar(1700) and can house any type of data (partnumber, description text, date, etc.) Language is English."

Comment: @Data Are you saying the way I am doing joins may cause the table to be selected prior to the join thus throwing an error when the ATTRIBUTEVALUE is being validated as a date?

Comment: @HeatherRoberts what he's saying is that you're storing multiple, different "real-world" data types in one column and when you're testing for dates, it's pulling all of these records into the set that it's filtering. Therefore, it's trying to convert your part number into a date, which probably isn't possible unless you format your part numbers as dates. This solution tests if something is a date and if it is attempts to format it as such.

Comment: @swasheck Thank you for the explanation. Do you know why I am getting the error on his case statement?

Comment: I want to award this to Data but I can't get the syntax surrounding the CASE to work.

Comment: @HeatherRoberts I fixed his syntax, it was missing the `END` for the `CASE`.  Try the updated code.

Comment: @JNK TYVM!! It works and everyone who helped me out rocks and should get a gold star for the day!

Comment: Sorry about forgetting the END.  My bad and thanks JNK for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, be sure that your query has nothing to do with that. It's all about the data in your tables. Also as I've seen the query, it seems you are joining some VIEWs and inside the view definitions might be some conversions that cause this error. If I where you, I'd do some simple queries on the tables and convert string columns to datetime one by one, until I found the error reference.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: These are flat tables with no relationship. I am not accessing any views. The query is fine and returns the proper data without 'ATTRIBUTEVALUE > dateadd(month,-12,getdate())' included in the query.

Comment: So it seems you know the problem already! What is the content of ATTRIBUTEVALUE column? do a simple convert(datetime, ATTRIBUTEVALUE) in a simple Select statement and see what happens then. What do you think?

Comment: ATTRIBUTEVALUE can hold several types of data, not just dates.  Running a simple select would cause errors because of the other data.

Comment: Wow, I got that. So you should do some validation on the value before conversion. I'd recommend LIKE operator to find out that the value whether datetime or not. Then do the conversion.